# Center and format text with OpenPDF

Tags: java, openpdf

I created a PDF file in Java using OpenPDF and inserted a paragraph. The problem is that I want to place it in the middle, not on the left. How can this be done?

Second question: How can I place a word with specific formatting in the test?
For example: "Hello and **welcome**" (welcome should be bold)

This is my code:

```java
Document document = new Document();
String PDFPath = "output.pdf";
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(PDFPath));
Font font_bold = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 16, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK);
Font font_normal = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 15, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Ordonnance", font_bold);
document.open();
document.add(p1);
document.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the alignment if you want to have the paragraph centred:
`p1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);`

To apply formatting to some parts of the text, you can divide it into several chunks. A `Chunk` in OpenPDF is a string with a certain *Font*. Instead of adding a `String` (unformatted) to the paragraph, you add a *Chunk*-object like `new Chunk("Hello and ", fontNormal)` which defines the text and the font to be used.

Here is the code for what you want to do according to the question:

```java
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("output.pdf"));
document.open();

Font fontNormal = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 15, Font.NORMAL);
Font fontBold = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 16, Font.BOLD);

Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
p1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
p1.add(new Chunk("Hello and ", fontNormal));
p1.add(new Chunk("welcome", fontBold));
document.add(p1);

document.close();
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Your first line had some weird declaration, but this should work:

```
Document document = new Document();
String PDFPath = "D:\\test.pdf";
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(PDFPath));
Font font_bold = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 16, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK);
Font font_normal = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 15, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Ordonnance", font_bold);
p1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
document.open();
document.add(p1);
document.close();
```

You just have to set the alignment of the paragraph